# Youtube Api: Python Search is not working throws Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: python, youtube-api

Trying to search youtube videos using this code: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py

But whatever I try I get below error even though I provided the api key:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 56, in <module>
    youtube_search(args)
  File "search.py", line 18, in youtube_search
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 226, in build
    credentials=credentials)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 358, in build_from_document
    credentials = _auth.default_credentials()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_auth.py", line 40, in default_credentials
    return oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1264, in get_application_default
    return GoogleCredentials._get_implicit_credentials()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tvapp_env\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1254, in _get_implicit_credentials
    raise ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError(ADC_HELP_MSG)
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Please help, im running this from windows machine.
Or is there better code to make youtube search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not running the app in either Google app engine or in Google compute engine. So there are not going to be any default credentials to use so you have to download the credentials from the google developer console first and use those credentials in your application. [Please refer this document for further details](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

Comment: Why does Google provide code examples on their API pages, if they give no indication it must be used within their own environments?

Comment: Did you read the answer first? I did not say it must be used within their environment. If the application running on different environment those credentials have to be created in the google developer console.